# form with jquery ui multiple sliders... only one value being submitted for all

Tags: jquery, forms, sliders

I've been schooling myself through stackoverflow and elsewhere and have learned a lot, but am still very new to this. I'm setting up a form with 5 sliders, the values of which will then post to a PHP page. Everything's working fine... except that the form submits the value of the final slider for EVERY slider. I think I need to use the `this` attribute or the `each` function, but I'm not sure how...

Here's my JS:

```
$(function(){

    var currentValue = $('#currentValue');

    $("#slider1,#slider2,#slider3,#slider4,#slider5").slider({ 
        range: "min",
        value:37,
        min:1,
        max: 500,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            currentValue.html(ui.value);
            $("input:hidden").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

});
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<input type=hidden name="slider1" id="slider1" class="slider-input" value="ui.value" />
<input type=hidden name="slider2" id="slider2" class="slider-input" value="ui.value" />
<input type=hidden name="slider3" id="slider3" class="slider-input" value="ui.value" />
<input type=hidden name="slider4" id="slider4" class="slider-input" value="ui.value" />
<input type=hidden name="slider5" id="slider5" class="slider-input" value="ui.value" />
```

Any suggestions? I'm stumped!

Comment: need an idea what the form html looks like for the hidden inputs. Your current selector will change the value for every hidden input in the page every time any slider is moved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of better understanding of structure of inputs in the form I will assume that the only hidden fields in form match each slider so they can be indexed.

SOmetimes it is easier to implement a plugin within an `each` loop so you can have simple access to each element of a collection within a javscript  closure. jQuery UI can give you access to the individual elements within the events , however not all plugins do so this pattern can be very helpful sometimes.

```
var $sliders=$("#slider1,#slider2,#slider3,#slider4,#slider5")

$sliders.each(function(){
    /* now have access to individual slider eleemnt*/
   var $slide=$(this);
      /* match input index to index of this slider*/
    var $input= $("input:hidden").eq(  $sliders.index($slide) );
    /* initiate slider on this element*/
     $slide.slider({ 
        range: "min",
        value:37,
        min:1,
        max: 500,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            currentValue.html(ui.value);
            /* assign value to correct input */
            $input.val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. The idea of an EACH loop makes sense. When I paste your code, though, the sliders lose their "sliding" functionality… they LOOK all right, but I can't move them. Any thoughts?

Comment: By the way, each slider appears in HTML like this: 
<div id="slider3" class="slider"></div>
You can see it in action at www.yayforeverything.com/deadlinedom/slider/form.html
(And thank you so much again)

Comment: FYI- you can't repeat ID's in a page...   slider and input have same ID

Comment: Sorry—when I couldn't get your code to work I replaced my original code. Your code is in now, and the silders won't slide. Also, I replaced the IDs in the hidden input fields with "input-slider1", "input-slider2", etc.... but I'm not sure what in your code I should replace to indicate that. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: OK.. with browser console open, as soon as you touch a slider this error gets thrown  `currentValue is not defined-line 32`  does that help you?  Use a console to look at errors

Comment: Charlie! It works! I added this line back in -- var currentValue = $('#currentValue'); -- and now it works! You're a god!

Comment: just pointing out how to troubleshoot, what this site is all about. Before you write another line... learn about console tools

Comment: I will. Thanks for your mentorship.